# htaccess redirect subdomain without changing url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi I already manage to redirect a page, `domain.com/location/england` to a `subdomain.domain.com` without changing url. Meaning to say. when typing to a browser, `subdomain.domain.com` the contents of it is the `domain.com/location/england` page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.co.uk/location/england/ [P]
```

My question is, it is possible that when displaying the page `domain.com/location/england` all their url link inside of this page. when clicking the url browser will still remain `subdomain.domain.com` and not changing? is this possible in .htaccess its like masking the url.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You cannot change any URL you write into your HTML code using `.htaccess`, you can only make the URL redirect to another.

Comment: what im trying to accomplish is that. we are creating subdomain to some of the links in our page. example domain.com/location/england . i need to display this page to england.subdomain.com which i already done. But what i want to achieve is. the links inside the page, when clicking. the url browser should be england.subdomain.com/sample/ and not domain.com/england/sample . all the links inside the page. which orginal came from domain.com/england.

Comment: This is not an issue that can be resolved using `.htaccess`. I assume that your links (`<a>` tags) are being written as absolute links, i.e. `https://example.com/england/sample`. In that case, simply rewrite them as `/england/sample`, for example - that would ensure that the domain name used is the current one.

Comment: Thank you Think123